# Finding the city with the max population

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a test table which looks like: 
[image]

And I want to find the city with the max population.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT City, count(*) AS [Population]
INTO #stats
FROM [Customer]
GROUP BY City

SELECT City, [Population]
FROM #stats
WHERE [Population] = 
(
    SELECT max([Population])
    FROM #stats
)

DROP TABLE #stats
```

Is it possible to do it in one query, without using a temp table?
What would other shorter practical ways be to get that result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can use:

```
SELECT TOP 1
city, COUNT(*) AS population
FROM Customer
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY population DESC
```

So just use the query you have already written to derive the population by city, but select only the top result and make sure you order by population in descending order.